# How to re-render ract-table after a button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, react-table

I have a list of users in a react-table based table component. The last column in the list shows a delete button. When the delete button is clicked, the user is deleted from the database. How can we re render the table to exclude the deleted user row. A simple page refresh is working fine but that is not the desired functionality.

Table column definition:

```
{
    Header: 'Manage User',
    accessor:'userid',
    Cell: (value) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <UserDeleteButton userId={value}></UserDeleteButton>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

function UserDeleteButton(props) {

```
const handleDelete = (userId) => {
  const jwt = localStorage.getItem('token');
  axios
  .delete('http://localhost:2000/api/user/' + userId)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('User deleted');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}

return (
    <button
        onClick={ () => handleDelete(props.userId) }
    >
    delete
    </button>
)
```

}

export default UserDeleteButton

I tried to use useContext but it is somehow not working for me. The issue is in the hierarchy i.e.

Table Component ---> List of columns ---> Delete Button

I was unable to access Table Component from delete button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the user state and delete function in the table component and then transfer them to the delete button as a prop, I hope your problem will be solved. I have prepared a rough code below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const TableComponent = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const handleDelete = (userId) => {
    const jwt = localStorage.getItem("token");

    axios
      .delete(`http://localhost:2000/api/user/${userId}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setUser(res.data);
        console.log("User deleted");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };

  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Manage User",
        accessor: "userid",
        Cell: (value) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <UserDeleteButton
                handleDelete={handleDelete}
                userId={value}
              ></UserDeleteButton>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  return (
    user && (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  );
};

export const UserDeleteButton = ({ handleDelete, userId }) => {
  return <button onClick={() => handleDelete(userId)}>delete</button>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use useState  hook from react

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react'
    
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);




    const handleDelete = (userId) => {
      const jwt = localStorage.getItem('token');
      axios
      .delete('http://localhost:2000/api/user/' + userId)
      .then((res) => {
setUser(res.data);
        console.log('User deleted');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
```

Comment: This will re render only the child component. The requirement is to re render the parent component i.e. the table.